# how prevent tomcat from automatically change server.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I need help with Tomcat configuration. I set virtual path to images from my project in server.xml. It works, but  after Tomcat restart it overwrites server.xml automatically and path to images disappears.
How can I repair this?

Comment: Are you setting up tomcat with some tool e.g. Ansible? It shouldn't override `server.xml` by itself once installed.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I use Eclipse, and I didn't use any additional tools to set up tomcat.